# iOS Actionsheet: Is it possible to detect which share option is chosen?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

For analytics purposes I want to detect when a user shares content of the iOS app using the action sheet, is it possible to detect which share option is chosen?

Comment: Do you actually mean `UIActivityViewController` or do you really mean the old, out-dated, and deprecated `UIActionSheet`?

Comment: Sorry for the dup flag. I thought it was a great question and in looking for an answer I found this. Look into using `completionWithItemsHandler`.